# Find $a$ and $b$ for the following equation: $x^2 - 10x + a = (x + b)^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

I'm starting A Level Maths and I've encountered this equation, which I have not seen at GCSE. I have tried to search for it on the web but I'm not sure how to phrase it, so here goes:

How would I:

Find $a$ and $b$ in the following equation:

$$x^2 - 10x + a = (x + b)^2$$

I know the answer is $a = 25, b = -5$. I am not sure what the process is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess so, that is literally the question. However, when expanding the bracket, x^2 is gone from the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x+b)^2=x^2+2bx+b^2$$

Comparing with $$x^2-10x+a,$$

You should be able to determine $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it. So you compare the -10x to 2bx and a to b^2. From there you solve the simultaneous equation. Ok thanks, didn't think it was that simple!

Comment: Why does $x^2+2bx+b^2=x^2-10x+a$ imply $2bx=-10x$ and $b^2=a$??

Comment: $x^2+2bx+b^2=x^2-10x+a$ implies $(2b+10)x+(b^2-a)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
The slope must be zero and the intercept is zero too.

Comment: @SiongthyeGoh Very nice, thanks.